# What happens when user tap app icon while app is running in background?

Tags: android

I want to create an activity that launched without UI on boot and restarted with UI when the user tap the icon.
I don't want multiple instances of this activity.
How I ensure that when user tap the icon (activity is already running), the app will be restarted (in order to display the UI), and the old instance will be destroyed?
Is "singleTask" will do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

singleTask is what you need for the activity to prevent it being loaded multiple times.

To fire something up on device start up you need to do listen for the boot;

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startService(this, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, this, SomeIntentService.class);
    }
}
```

with a manifest like;

```
    <receiver android:name="BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But if you want any process long running, you need a foreground service;

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)

Has fantastic documentation on how to get your service into a persistant state. It's dead simple to get an IntentService going, you just need to override a single method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)

Then store data perhaps in sharedpreferences or a database and your activity accesses the data store.

Comment: Thanks! sound good.Just to verify that I understand : you suggest that on boot my activity will launch an IntentService and when the user tap the icon, the activity will (automatically) be destroyed then launched while the service still running?

Comment: Yes! :) So gut your activity and all the work should be done in the service. The activity just monitors the service via persistant storage.